# Chrome refuses to find a defined perl script

Tags: perl, google-chrome, defined

I have a perl search tool that is so much faster than windows search.
I thought I'd give it a graphic interface and the simplest was to use html.

`IE` has no problem with it and it runs fine - but I don't use `IE` any more as `chrome` is so much better.

But in `Chrome` I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: getFiles is not defined
```

the script is defined in the html header as:

```
<script language="PerlScript" type="text/PerlScript">
sub getFiles
{
...
}
```

This is client-side - not on any server.

Any ideas as to why this should happen?

Firexox gives the same result.

Comment: You will have to show your HTML / JavaScript for us to guess. Out of interest, what is this Perl search tool?

Comment: Please expand on what your code is doing. As it stands, this question is unanswerable. I would _guess_ that you've got 'script defined in html header' - which I'm not sure will work, because Chrome doesn't have a perl parser built in.

Comment: It's really quite simple. Searching both for files and for strings in files is so much faster with Perl - Windows never seems to even complete its search - and even indexed is soo much slower. As what I search for is usually the consequence of changes to code I've installed the tool on the server instead. If anyone wants the code I'll either post or mail it

Answer (score 6):

Your script will *only* work with Internet Explorer, and not with any other browser, because only  IE can interact with a part of the Windows operating system, called the "Windows Script Host" (WSH). WSH can run any script file in any scripting language, as long as that language interpreter follows a certain specification (the ActiveX Scripting Engine must be a COM component implementing the *IActiveScriptParse* Interface)

And it only works, because you (or someone else) has configured your machine to link IE with the perl interpreter.

I think when you install ActiveState Perl, its installation wizard asks you to create that IE/WSH/Perl Link. (It is optional)

You can check IEs  "internet options", there is a configuration option where you can enable/disable that link (because it can potentially harm your computer).

If it is disabled, you'd get an error message similar to [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/805961/i-get-a-windows-script-host-error-message-when-i-download-a-standardlegit-js).